# Programação em C utilizando CodeBlocks da dando erro na programação abaixo

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float num1 = 10;
    float num2 = 20;

    int resposta;

    num1 < num2 ? printf("Sim/n") : printf("Nao/n");

    num1 < num2 ? resposta = 10 : resposta = -10;

    printf("i%/n", resposta);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O operador ternário apenas pode produzir um valor e não uma instrução.

Logo em vez de:

```
num1 < num2 ? printf("Sim/n") : printf("Nao/n");
num1 < num2 ? resposta = 10 : resposta = -10;
```

Tem de ser:

```
printf(num1 < num2 ? "Sim\n":"Nao\n");
resposta = num1 < num2 ? 10: -10;
```

Note que tem os `\n` invertidos e escritos como `/n`. O mesmo se aplica para o `%i` no ultimo `printf` que ficou escrito como `i%`.

[Exemplo do código com estas alterações no Ideone](https://ideone.com/lgpRk4)